# <a> tag target=_blank from an iframe to a new window

Tags: html, iframe, href

I have to load a page in a new window, and my `<a href>` is in an iframe, so it doesn't work. The link opens inside of the same iframe and I don't want that, I want it to be in a completely new window. Anyone knows a solution please?

```
<a href="https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0944711316301891" id="lien" target="_blank">Lien vers une étude publiée sur ScienceDirect</a>
```

^I don't want it to load in the iframe the button is in

Comment: All else being equal, the `target` attribute will cause the link to open in a new window (or tab, but not the same iframe). If it doesn’t then something must be interfering with it (maybe some JS, or a `sandbox` attribute).

Answer (score -1):

Use JavaScript's `window.open()`. You can launch it from the `<a>` tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: basically I would do ```<script> myfunction { "window.open(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0944711316301891", "_blank" } </script> and then add onclick="myfunction()"``` on my ahref?

Comment: u can also do `<a href="javascript:window.open()" ....`
And IMO u need another name and not _blank, but try it

Comment: worked very well, thanks for saving me a few hours before deadline